# This may be a stupid question but can juju work on a kubernetes cluster that was created and deployed outside of it

Tags: juju, nagios3, kubernetes

I'm asking because I have been trying to get some monitoring and log aggregation to work and when I do the juju side of install to an already existing kubernetes cluster it has a status of waiting and all documentation I can find has instructions on deploying kubernetes via juju.  Its like the juju controller can't see a externally created kubernetes cluster.....is this behaviour expected and I'm just unfamiliar or is there some sort of juju component needed to communicate with the external kubernetes cluster that will allow the jujucharm to get out of the status of waiting and never loking like it communicate with anything outside of its environment.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it cannot control all the components.

The juju `add-k8s` command is what you need:

> Information about the cluster is needed in order to add it to Juju. This is found within the main Kubernetes configuration file that can be copied over from the Kubernetes master node (and saved as ~/.kube/config). We can then take advantage of the add-k8s command as it will parse the configuration file if copied to the above path. This allows us to quickly add the cluster.
>
> Note that the conjure-up installer adds the cluster for you.

https://docs.jujucharms.com/2.5/en/clouds-k8s#using-kubernetes-with-juju_1